How to Select Records with Specific 'uuid' Value Across Types
I’m currently working with ArcadeDB and need some help with a specific query.
I’ve successfully used the following query to find all types containing a field called "uuid":
SELECT FROM schema:types WHERE properties CONTAINS (name = 'uuid');

However, I’m now looking to extend this query to find all records across these types where the "uuid" field has a specific value, denoted :myUuid.
Could someone please guide me in constructing a query for this purpose?
Thanks in advance for your assistance! Your help is greatly appreciated.

One workaround could be to extend the types from a super type and query the super type with a WHERE clause. I don't suppose it is possible to use multiple SELECT targets unless they are indexes or RIDs
